# Pass data to unfocused screen in react native on app load

Tags: react-native

I have a bottom tab navigator with 4 screens. One of the screens is an 'alerts' screen that will have a badge on the icon that shows the number of alerts the user has. Super original, I know. Surprisingly I can't find anything about this on here. Where do I call my fetch function to get that number? I'm trying to figure out how to get that number to the alerts screen when the user opens the app / is on the homescreen.

In my SignInScreen I get data from facebook then navigate to the homescreen:

```
 await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name&access_token=${token}`).then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => {

          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',
          {
              UserName : json.name,
              FBID : json.id,
              email : json.email

          });
```

In my homescreen I fetch data for the user on ComponentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){

   this.GetDataAndPopulateHomeScreen()

}
```

Here is the relevant code from my MainTabNavigator file:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen, 
  },
  config

);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <MaterialIcons name="home"  color={focused ? "hotpink":"white"} size={32}  />
  ),
};

HomeStack.path = '';


const AlertsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Alerts: AlertsScreen,
  },
  config
);
AlertsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Alerts',


  ////********NEED TO PUT A BADGE ON THIS ICON HERE with the alert count***********////
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <MaterialIcons name="notifications-none"  color={focused ? "hotpink":"white"} size={32}  />
  ),
};

AlertsStack.path = '';

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  PostStack,
  AlertsStack,
  SettingsStack,  
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
      style: {
          backgroundColor: '#1c92d2' // TabBar background
      }
  }
});

tabNavigator.path = '';


export default tabNavigator;
```

Nothing out of the ordinary right?  This should be super simple pointsfor someone.
I've tried calling the function in the MainTabNavigator file. I don't really know how else to tackle this. There is a lot of documentation on how to pass data when you click on buttons but what if i'm trying to pass data to an unfocused screen? How do you guys do this?

Thank you.

here is my app on the home screen, I need to see a number badge on the alerts icon:

[image: here I am on the home screen, I need to see a number badge on the alerts icon]

Comment: First of all, this is not calling data to an unfocused screen, rather, your bottom bar navigation, which is visible, needs that count. It depends if you are using redux or not and other factors, i would suggest to edit the question, remove non helpful lines making question lengthy, and actually add more usefull details. So we can help better. Thanks.

Comment: **DOCS**

const HomeIconWithBadge = (props) => {
  // You should pass down the badgeCount in some other ways like react context api, redux, mobx or event emitters.
  return <IconWithBadge {...props} badgeCount={3} />;  
}
export default HomeIconWithBadge

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal thanks for trying !

Comment: I’d like to avoid third parties like redux if possible. I find it hard to believe this trivial /common of a task would require one.

Comment: @Jared There is no-way you could achieve this >> 'Make unfocused screen update 
 itself' without using some sort app-global-data mechanism like redux or mobx...

Comment: Ok if you post this as the answer I’ll select it in a couple days of no one knows a way